# Procedural tests in googletest?

Tags: c++, googletest

Instead of using the `TEST_F` macro, I would like to procedurally add a test.

The use case is to implement data driven integrating testing; I want a folder of test files, and to launch a separate test for each file, with test's name being the file name.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have a look at [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests)

Comment: Recently function [RegisterTest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L2434) was added in gtest.h header, which might be what you're looking for